# PowerBI. Create a tile using API

Tags: powerbi

We need to add functionality that will exports some data into PowerBI account.
There should be created new tile for every new export.

However in API manual I have found only GET operations for Tiles:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt465742.aspx

Does someone know if it is possible at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a tile programmatically is not yet supported. We're tracking ideas for improvements here: http://ideas.powerbi.com.  Would suggest you submit an idea so we can track and let you know if we add this capability.